# Filter list of Cities with latitude and longitude on given Distance from another City (with lat/long)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, filter, distance

How can I filter a given list of cities with longitude and latitude based on a given distance (in km) from another city with longitude and latitude.

I would like use Google Maps API (javascript) or another solution that fits.

```
cities = {
          ['zürich','47.368650', '8.539183'],
          ['City2','21.568650', '2.439183'],
          ['City3','41.568650', '4.439183']
}


distance   = 2; //2 km
targetCity = ['zürich','47.368650', '8.539183'];
```

need: `getNearCities(targetCity,distance,cities);`

Thank you

Comment: You can see the Haversine formula on this page http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: check out the google distance matrix api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to the http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript

```
var cities = [
    ['zürich', 47.368650, 8.539183],
    ['City2', 21.568650, 2.439183],
    ['City3', 41.568650, 4.439183]
];

var dist = calculateDistance(cities[0][2], cities[0][3], cities[1][4], cities[1][5], 'K');
alert(dist);

function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180
    var theta = lon1 - lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit == "K") {
        dist = dist * 1.609344
    }
    if (unit == "N") {
        dist = dist * 0.8684
    }
    return dist + unit
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunka81L/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google Maps [google.maps.geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), or implement the [Haversine formula.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

To use Google Maps the call is

```
 google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(ll1, ll2)
```

where ll. and ll2 are `LatLng` objects created using `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [google.maps.geometry.spherical namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical). With it you get the distance between two points.

```
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(###,###);
var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(###,###);
var maxDistance = 2; //in km

var withinRange = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween( origin, destination) <= maxDistance);
```